# Как отключить кэш раз и навсегда на странице

Tags: html, кэширование

Что нужно прописать на странице, чтобы все браузеры, которые заходят на эту страницу, без исключения никогда не обращались в кэш, а каждый раз заново перечитывали стили и скрипты из присоединённых файлов, т.к. там постоянно бывают изменения. Следующие предписания абсолютно не дают никакого результата:

```
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Fri, 20 Mar 2014 00:00:00 GMT" />
```

Также безрезультатны аналогичные комманды на PHP:

```
<?php
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: Fri, 20 Mar 2014 00:00:00 GMT');
?>
```

Как отключить кэш для всего (css и js), навсегда и для всех браузеров?

Comment: И не дадут. Это указания кеширования самой страницы, а не включаемых файлов. Для включаемых файлов надо отдельно отдавать заголовок Cache-control, например средствами web сервера. Или делать динамические url для самих включаемых файлов, вроде `<script src="x.js?rnd=123>` где 123 версия файла или вообще случайное число

Comment: @Mike, если бы для каждого файла можно было бы один раз прописать, а то эту циферку после вопроса постоянно менять приходится

Comment: так у вас же все равно вся страница создается php файлом, так что никто не мешает эту циферку генерить динамически в коде. А что касается заголовков отдаваемых браузером, да, достаточно прописать их один раз на директорию нужную или на весь сайт целиком, например. В конфиге web-сервера или файлах .htaccess

Comment: @Mike спасибо большое. Не могли бы Вы вынести свой комментарий в ответ, чтобы я мог пометить его как правильный. И если нетрудно - подсказать, где разместить и как написать файл .htaccess, не могу найти его на сервере?

Comment: как написать, зависит от конкретного web сервера. у apache и nginx совершенно разные языки описания. вот например https://ruhighload.com/%D0%9A%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8+%D0%B8+cache-control там конечно говорится как наоборот заставить кешировать, так что надо просто написать другие значения для того что бы сократить время кеширования

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оптимальным вариантом оказалось следующее:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?rnd=<?= rand(0, 999) ?>">
```

Comment: Это сработает лишь в первые полтысячи раз, а потом рандом начнёт слишком часто повторяться и попадать в кэш. Вам уже писали правильное решение — Cache-Control

Comment: @andreymal a Cache-Control вообще не работает, я же упомянул об этом в тексте вопроса

Comment: Вам же уже писали в самом первом комментарии, что Cache-Control должен применться не к веб-странице, а к тому файлу, которому нужно отключить кэш

Comment: @andreymal https://ruhighload.com/%D0%9A%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8+%D0%B8+cache-control - то есть эти изменения нужно вносить в .htaccess, верно?

Comment: Вероятно да, если у вас Apache

Comment: С другой стороны название файла можно генерировать с помощью таймстампа, и тогда не будет проблем

Answer (score 3):

На мой взгляд оптимальное решение по отключению кеширования должно включать и теги, и рандомную версию статичного контента, и отключение кеширования на сервере в настройках хостинга:

```
<!-- Теги с директивами "не кешировать" для браузера и "узлов" веб-сети -->
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />

<!-- динамическое назначение версии статичному контенту - стили и скрипты js -->
<!-- пример для PHP -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?v=<?= time(); ?>">
<script src="js/bandle.js?v=<?= time(); ?>"></script>
```

Вряд ли кому-либо надо запрещать кеширование изображений...

P.S. Кеширование мешает только при отладке сайта, а при плановой работе оно (кеширование), как правило, только в помощь.